# Пунктуация и вид синтаксической конструкции

Tags: пунктуация

***Вечером я загнала машину в гараж, и мы расстались, боюсь, что надолго*** (Л. Улицкая).

Правильно ли выбраны знаки препинания в приведенном предложении? Как можно определить его грамматику?

Comment: Я в этом не спец, выскажу только предположение: не заменить ли запятую перед "боюсь" на точку с запятой? Мне так "захотелось" из-за увеличенной паузы. А тире не подходит там?

Comment: Вас, наверное, интересует пунктуация при вводном слове?

Comment: Честно говоря, меня интересует всё: интонация, пунктуация и грамматика второй части предложения. Серж, слово "боюсь" управляет сочетанием "что надолго", это не такое простое вводное слово. Мне кажется, что оборот "боюсь что надолго" читается как единое сочетание:... и мы расстались,  боюсь что (=вероятно) надолго. Обособляется присоединительный оборот, но вроде бы запятой хватит для обозначения паузы. Но это всё предположения, а они должны быть подтверждены правилами.

Comment: Sharon, что скажете по поводу тех знаков, о которых я подумал? Всё не то?

Comment: Артем, точка с запятой здесть точно не подойдет, так как этот знак ставится между предложениями с отдаленной тематикой, а здесь отнесенный к предложению оборот. Тире возможно для присоединительных конструкций, но оно обычно ставится при отсутствии союза или его аналога, а здесь в роли союза выступает "боюсь что". Поэтому я думаю, что запятой хватит. А правы Вы в том, что оборот присоединительный.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, за разъяснения! ;)

Comment: Я бы тире поставил перед "боюсь".

Comment: Я думаю, что это двухчастная конструкция, основная пауза перед союзом И. Обособленный оборот относится ко второй части, там нет подчеркнутой паузы, она скорее произносительная. А тире разделит предложение на три части, да и графика получается некрасивая. Мне-то хочется убрать запятую перед ЧТО и как-то объяснить это.

Comment: @Sharon, фраза носит разговорный характер. А в разговорной речи правила ненормированы. Но, в любом случае, нам не мешает ничего поставить точку или троеточие  после " расстались". И считать последнее предложение присоединительной  конструкцией.